# Asynchronous task with condition

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I need to implement a task which would run asynhronously some maximum amount of times but stop earlier if some condition is met. As a simple example there's task generating a random number from 1 to 100 and it runs 4 times with some interval and return ther last generated number, but if one of generated numbers is > 50 then it must stop iterations and return that number. I was thinking about `ScheduledExecutorService` with `scheduleAtFixedRate` but not sure how to stop it properly when the condition is met.

Comment: Is it important that each iteration runs asynchronously? If so, please edit the question to explain why.

Comment: Call `Future.cancel()` or `ExecutorService.shutdown()`.

Comment: @TimMoore no, each iteration doesn't have to run asynchronously, just all iterations in separate thread